# Converting a File to a directory of which it is unclear if it exists to an URI with a reliable trailing slash

Tags: java, uri

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // legacy code comes around with a File
    File baseDir = new File("C:\\path\\to\\parent\\directory");
    mkdirs(baseDir.toURI());
}

// method in a foreign module using URI
static void mkdirs(URI base) {
    URI toCreate = base.resolve("folders/below");
    System.out.println(toCreate);
}
```

If the directory `C:\path\to\parent\directory` actually exists on my hard drive, this works as I expect and prints:

```
file:/C:/path/to/parent/directory/folders/below
```

However, if not, it prints:

```
file:/C:/path/to/parent/folders/below
```

This is because `File.toURI()` creates an URI with a trailing `/`, denoting a directory, in case if `File.isDirectory()`, and the way `URI.resolve()` is designed. Anyway, given the case that I know that `baseDir` specifies a directory, but I do not know if this directory already exists or should be created with the folders underneath. What is the recommended way to turn `baseDir` into an URI with a reliable trailing slash?

Changing `new File("C:\\path\\to\\parent\\directory")` to `new File("C:\\path\\to\\parent\\directory\\")` (adding the trailing slash here) does not change anything.

I came up with this, but there should be a better way to do that:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    File baseDir = new File("C:\\path\\to\\parent\\directory");

    URI baseDirUri = baseDir.toURI();
    String baseDirUriString = baseDirUri.toString();
    if (!baseDirUriString.endsWith("/")) {
        baseDirUri = URI.create(baseDirUriString.concat("/"));
    }
    mkdirs(baseDirUri);
}
```

Comment: Anything conceptually wrong with checking if the base directory exists on the hard drive, and if does not - creating it, then proceeding with the above algorithm?

Comment: Yes, unluckily, since this is what the mkdirs() function shall do which I am required to call from another module, for sake of clear responsibilities.